# Wait panel on smartgwt

Tags: smartgwt

Do you know any components in smartgwt in order to do some like this?

[image]

I´ve done it using several componets, Labels, Camva, Img, Layouts....

Thanks

Well, I have found this option SC.showPrompt and SC.clearPrompt but I think that it´s not possible add images into of panel.

Answer (score 2):

I did this in the past you can have a try

```
public class Attente extends Window{

private Label message = new Label();
public String getMessage() {
    return message.getTitle();
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message.setContents(message) ;
}
private Img image = new Img("64/Wait-icon.png",64,64);

/**
 * Instantie un nouveau attente.
 */
public Attente(){
    this.setTitle("Opération en cours, veuillez patienter");        
    this.setShowHeader(true);
    this.centerInPage();
    this.setAutoCenter(true);
    this.setWidth(300);
    this.setHeight(140);
    this.setShowCloseButton(false);
    this.setShowMinimizeButton(false);
    this.setShowMaximizeButton(false);
    VLayout layout = new VLayout();
    HLayout hLayout = new HLayout();
    message.setHeight(15);
    message.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
    message.setStyleName("plVersionCatalogue");
    hLayout.addMember(new LayoutSpacer());
    hLayout.addMember(image); 
    hLayout.addMember(new LayoutSpacer());
    layout.addMember(new LayoutSpacer());
    layout.addMember(hLayout);
    layout.addMember(new LayoutSpacer());
    layout.addMember(message);
    this.addItem(layout);
}
```

}

And in the code I had a singleton instance of this class which I can use like this when I need:

```
MyContext.getAttente().show();
```

or

```
MyContext.getAttente().hide();
```